# Undefined mixin 'box-shadow'

Tags: scss

Помогите, как исправить всё это? 
В интернете совет расположить миксины выше файлов со стилями , но у меня все равно выдает ошибку, хотя тень применяется на веб-странице.

[image]

Файл **header.scss**:

```
.header {
        height: 80px;
        background: #fff;
        @include box-shadow(0 1px 3px 0 rgba(#000, .2));
    }
```

**mixins.scss** :

```
  @mixin box-shadow($params) {
        box-shadow: $params;
        -moz-box-shadow: $params;
    }
```

**main.scss** - главный файл с подключениями:

```
    //var 
$white: #f6f6f6;
$blue: #33c1e3;



//layout

@import "_misc/mixins.scss";
@import "_misc/adjustment.scss";
@import "_misc/normalize.scss";

//styles
@import "sections/header";
```

Comment: Выглядит вроде нормально, скорее всего придется выложить сборку.

Comment: @MedvedevDev то есть?

Comment: то есть приведенный вами код выглядит как рабочий, проблема скорее всего в чем-то ещё (в том числе я например не очень понимаю где эта ошибка возникает, незнакомый мне интерфейс). Не понятно каким образом вы собираете проект (сборщик, или же это браузерное преобразование scss). Нужно больше вводных + желательно выложить куда-то архивчик/репозиторий со всеми файлами (кроме node_modules, если используются сборщики), тогда было бы проще разобраться. Предположительно вы пытаетесь собрать header.scss (возможно непреднамеренно, просто сборщик неправильно настроен).

Comment: Для начала, скажите чем собираете css, если сборщик (gulp/grunt/webpack/etc.) - выложите содержимое конфиг файла.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, Koala

Comment: тогда вам надо настроить её правильно. Судя по тому, что стили применяются - main.scss таки собирается, а ошибка возникает потому, что программа так же пытается собрать отдельно header.scss, вам нужно сделать так, что бы собирался только main.scss

Comment: спасибо,попробую что нибудь сделать с этим